# I Use LumiSoft.Net load email Attachment excel

Tags: c#, webforms, gmail

```
private void loademail()
{

    string UserName = "";
    string Pwd = "";

    POP3_Client pop3 = new POP3_Client();
    pop3.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
    pop3.Login(UserName, Pwd);
    POP3_ClientMessageCollection messages = pop3.Messages;
    if (messages.Count <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    POP3_ClientMessage message = messages[0];

    byte[] messageBytes = message.MessageToByte();
    Mail_Message mime_message = Mail_Message.ParseFromByte(messageBytes);

    MIME_Entity[] attachments = mime_message.GetAttachments(true, true);

    foreach (MIME_Entity entity in attachments)
    {
        if (entity.ContentDisposition != null)
        {
            string fileName = entity.ContentDisposition.Param_FileName;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\email\");
                if (!dir.Exists) dir.Create();

                string path = Path.Combine(dir.FullName, fileName);
                MIME_b_SinglepartBase byteObj = (MIME_b_SinglepartBase)entity.Body;
                Stream decodedDataStream = byteObj.GetDataStream();
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    LumiSoft.Net.Net_Utils.StreamCopy(decodedDataStream, fs, 4000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    message.MarkForDeletion();
    pop3.Disconnect();
}
```

LumiSoft.Net Use this.
I want to use C# to read the attachment excel here. I get errors here
pop3.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false); <===error
get message :220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q23sm412689pfg.192 - gsmtp
How to solve??

Comment: Um... [SMTP wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol): _"User-level email clients typically use SMTP **only for sending messages** to a mail server for relaying"_ (emphasis mine).

Comment: @John So can't use?

Comment: You can't use SMTP for receiving e-mail, no. You need to see if Google makes a [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) address available for receiving e-mail.

Comment: How to use here??

Comment: I have found the answer thanks